# Como alimentar uma tableView de uma tela com informações de outra tela?

Tags: swift, uitableview

Boa noite, tenho 3 telas no meu app para comprar senhas, a última delas possui uma tableView alimentada pelas senhas compradas pelo usuário em uma tela anterior. Ele deve escolher uma senha e a mesma aparecer no resumo do pedido dele na tela seguinte em uma tableView, se o usuário quiser comprar outra senha, ele pode clicar em "próxima senha" e retornar para a tela de senhas e escolher outra para ser somada a que foi escolhida anteriormente, mas como fazer com que as informações sejam somadas após a escolha das novas senhas?

O fluxo segue assim:

Tela de categorias: O usuário escolhe qual categoria e vai pra tela de senhas
Tela de senhas: O usuário escolhe a senha e vai pra tela de resumo
Tela de resumo: A tableView é alimentada com a senha escolhida e se o usuário quiser comprar outra, volta pra tela de categorias.

Classe onde são escolhidas as senhas:

```
import UIKit

class ComprarSenhaViewController {

     static let sharedInstance = ComprarSenhaViewController()

     var senhasSelecionadas = Array<String>()
     var senhaAtual = Senha()

     @IBAction func fecharPedido(sender: AnyObject) {
        SenhaController.sharedInstance.senha = self.senhaAtual

        senhasSelecionadas.append("\(senhaAtual.id)")

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let novoNavigation = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResumoViewController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(novoNavigation, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Classe onde mostra o resumo das senhas escolhidas:

```
import UIKit

class ResumoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    static let sharedInstance = ResumoViewController()

    var senhasSelecionadas = Array<String>()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return senhasSelecionadas.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let row = indexPath.row
        let idSenha = senhasSelecionadas[row]
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel!.text = idSenha
        return cell
    }

    func carregarResumoSenhas(){

        ComprarSenhaViewController.sharedInstance.senhasSelecionadas = self.senhasSelecionadas
        let idsenha = SenhaController.sharedInstance.senha.id
        senhasSelecionadas.append("\(idsenha)")

        tableView.reloadData()

    }
    @IBAction func proximaSenha(sender: AnyObject) {        
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let novoNavigation = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CategoriaViewController")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(novoNavigation, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        carregarResumoSenhas()

    }
```

Comment: Você está usando delegate? [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) is a design pattern that enables a class or structure to hand off (or delegate) some of its responsibilities to an instance of another type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não use *Delegate* porque você vai estar criando uma dependência desnecessária. `senhasSelecionadas` é uma variável pública e `ComprarSenhaViewController` tem uma referência ao `ResumoViewController`, então é só atribuir um valor a `senhasSelecionadas` logo antes do `pushViewController`.

```
...
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let resumoController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResumoViewController")
resumoController.senhasSelecionadas = senhasSelecionadas
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resumoController, animated: true)
...
```

Também não entendi por que você está usando *Singleton* nos teus `ViewControllers`.

Comment: Alice, se vc estah usando Singleton para compartilhar informacoes entre ViewControllers (VC's) entao esta nao eh a melhor forma de faze-lo. Supondo que voce tenha dois VC's em que um chama o outro. VC1 -> VC2. Entao exponha uma propriedade no VC2 (torne-a publica) para que o VC1 posso atribui-la antes de chamar o push ou no prepareForSegue (se estiver usando o storyboard). Caso voce precisa atualizar o VC1 com alguma informacao do VC2 ou simplesmente notificar alguma mudanca entao use delegate e protocol. Caso os VC's nao tenham uma relacao direta pense em utilizar Notifications ou KVO.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando [protocolo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html), como foi mencionado, você pode fazer isso da seguinte maneira: a definição do protocolo ficará na sua classe `ResumoViewController`, este vou chamar de `ResumoDelegate`.

Neste protocolo vou definir um método que irá retornar todas as senhas compradas, e assim no `viewWillAppear` busca essa lista e atualiza a tabela de resumo.

```
protocol ResumoDelegate {
    func listaSenhas() -> [Senha]
}

class ResumoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var delegate: ResumoDelegate?
    var senhasSelecionadas: [Senha] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        senhasSelecionadas = delegate?.listaSenhas()

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Agora, a implementação deste método fica na sua tela `ComprarSenhaViewController`:

```
class ComprarSenhaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ResumoDelegate {
    var senhasSelecionadas: [Senha] = []

    @IBAction func fecharPedido(sender: AnyObject) {
        senhasSelecionadas.append(senhaAtual)

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let resumoController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ResumoViewController")
        resumoController.delegate = self

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(resumoController, animated: true)
    }

    func listaSenhas() -> [Senha] {
        return senhasSelecionadas
    }
}
```

Note que também precisa incluir o `ResumoDelegate` na assinatura da classe e antes do `pushViewController` definir o `delegate` como a própria classe.

Comment: Eu tentei usar o delegate, mas não deu certo, usei o sharedInstance para compartilhar as informações de uma tela para outra e consegui. :) Obrigada.